# Strict convexity of a power of Euclidean norm

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces

> Is the Euclidean norm $\| \cdot \|^p$ strictly convex for all $p \ge 1$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If not, does it hold for $p \ge 2$.

The euclidean norm is defined by $\| x \|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x^2_i$.

I am interested in the resulting inequality that for $x$ and $y$ linear independent vectors in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ it follows:
$$|\frac{x+y}{2}|^p < \frac{|x|^p}{2}+ \frac{|y|^p}{2}.$$

Let $p \in (1,\infty)$. Let $x \neq y$, then we can calulate
$$f(tx +(1-t)y) = |tx+(1-t)y|^p \le (t|x|+(1-t)|y|)^p < t|x|^p+(1-t)|y|^p \le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$$
for all $t \in (0,1)$ due to the convexity of the euclidean norm and due to the strict convexity of $a^p$ or all $p > 1$. Is this calculation right?
About the inequality: Let $t = 1/2$ then it follows
$$\left|\frac{x+y}{2}\right|^p < \frac{|x|^p}{2}+ \frac{|y|^p}{2}.$$

Comment: What did you try? For starters, consider $p=1$ and $x=2y$. Will the same argument work if $p>1$?

Comment: Nothing yet, i would just like to know if it is true. This is neither homework nor an excercise. If you know the answer to my question, please enlighten me. Though you are right I need to tad that not only $x \neq y$ but also that they are linear independent. Thanks, I will edit my question.

Comment: when $\left( 1 , 2 \right]$ the norm $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert ^{p}$ is strongly convex and thus strictly convex :)
perhaps you should try to prove that they are strongly convex instead because you can compute the Hessian and check that if they are positive definite. for the strictly convex function it can still be positive semidefinite as convex function.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Did you take a look at my attempted calculation?